# Largest Number that cannot be expressed as 6nm +- n +- m

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm looking to find out if there is a largest integer that cannot be written as $6nm \pm n \pm m$ for $n,m$ elements of the natural numbers.  For example, there are no values of $n,$m for which $6nm \pm n \pm m = 17.$  Other numbers which have no solution are $25$, $30$, and $593$.  Can all numbers above a certain point be written as $6nm \pm n \pm m$ or will there always be gaps?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want non-zero $m,n$? Because $(m,n)=(17,0)$ solves $6nm+n+m=17$.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  For n,m > 0.

Answer (score 2):

This question is equivalent to the Twin Prime Conjecture.

Let's look at the three cases:

$$6nm+n+m =\frac{(6n+1)(6m+1)-1}{6}\\
6nm+n-m = \frac{(6n-1)(6m+1)+1}{6}\\
6nm-n-m = \frac{(6n-1)(6m-1)-1}{6}
$$

So if $N$ is of one of these forms, then:

$$6N+1=(6n+1)(6m+1)\\
6N-1=(6n-1)(6m+1)\\
6N+1=(6n-1)(6m-1)$$

If $6N-1$ and $6N+1$ are both primes, then there is no non-zero solutions.

If $6N-1$ is composite, its factorization is of the form $(6n-1)(6m+1)$.

If $6N+1$ is composite, its factorization is either of the form $(6n-1)(6m-1)$ or $(6n+1)(6m+1)$.

So the question is equivalent to the Twin Prime Conjecture. I don't think this will be solved on this site, unless it is just a reference to a resolution of the conjecture elsewhere. Currently, the state of knowledge about twin primes is thin.

For example, when $N=31$, $6N-1=5\cdot 37 = (6\cdot 1-1)(6\cdot 6+1)$. So with $m=1,n=6$, we get $31 = 6\cdot 1\cdot 6 +1 -6$. Alternative, $6N+1=11\cdot 17=(6\cdot 2-1)(6\cdot 3-1)$. So $(m,n)=(2,3)$ and $31=6\cdot2\cdot 3 -2-3$.

Comment: Yes, I knew that.  I was seeing if I worded the question differently if anyone would be able to solve the equivalent problem.  Since it took you virtually no time at all to realize they were the same problem, I guess my realization that they were the same problem accomplished nothing toward solving this problem.  Thank you for reading and responding.

Comment: Yeah, usually such reformulations are not much help for problems people have been trying to tackle for ages. I came up with a symmetric polynomial formulation for Fermat's Last once: If $p>2$ is an odd integer and $x,y,z$ integers then $x^p+y^p+z^p=0$ iff ( $x+y+z=0$ and $xyz=0$.)

Comment: Terence Tao (a  Fields Medallist) is working on the twin primes conjecture.

Comment: Lots of smart people have tackled it, but recent progress in the field has been remarkable. I still don't expect an answer that will be suitable for this forum. @user254665