# simple hyperbolic Diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

How can we show that there are infinitely many integers $C$ such that the simple hyperbolic diophantine equation:
$$6xy ± x ± y = C$$ gives a non-integer solutions for $x, y$, except at $(0, ±C), (±C,0)$?

Some of these values of $C = \{3,5,7,10,…\}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496106/diophantine-equation-with-application-to-twin-primes and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324324/proof-of-minor-claim-related-to-the-twin-primes-conjecture and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550916/find-all-integers-n-such-that-n-neq-6xy-pm-x-pm-y and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416570/largest-number-that-cannot-be-expressed-as-6nm-n-m and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698021/does-proving-the-following-statement-equate-to-proving-the-twin-prime-conjecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [OEIS sequence A002822](http://oeis.org/A002822) "Numbers n such that 6n-1, 6n+1 are twin primes". Thus, proving there are infinitely many of these numbers is equivalent to proving the [twin prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) conjecture.

Comment: thank you very much for the feedback.